# Using DataPager for Datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, datapager

Can we use a DataPager for a DataList?
I've done it but the following exception has occurred !!!

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: Control 'DataList1' does not implement IPageableItemContainer.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataPager.FindPageableItemContainer() +500609
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataPager.OnInit(EventArgs e) +33
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataPager needs the paged control to implement [IPageableItemContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.ipageableitemcontainer.aspx) interface. The interface has been introduced in 3.5, so old controls don't implement this interface.

Workaround solution for you can be to create a dummy control that implements this interface and provides necessary paging logic based on data source to be used for your data list.

EDIT: BTW, you can always use ListView control instead of DataList.